# Phone number validation regular expression consist one plus sign in start and preceding digits

Tags: javascript, java, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am trying to validate phone number but cannot.

My requirement is phone number consist only of digits and + (plus symbol). The + can be only the first character.

For example: +123456489

I am using this regular expression but it is not working:

```
/^\+(?:[0-9]??)$/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The regex is `^\+?\d+$`. In HTML `pattern` attribute, it looks like `pattern="\+?\d+"`. If you need to limit the number of digits to a specific amount replace `\d+` with `\d{n}` where `n` is the exact number of digits you want.

Answer (score 16):

I'd use this instead:

```
^\+?\d*$
```

Matches your + at the start, then any digit, dash, space, dot, or brackets.

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/mS9gD7

Comment: only digit and plus sign is allowed.

Comment: @Sami in that case, even simpler: `^\+?\d*$`

Answer (score 9):

How about this?

```
^[\+\d]?(?:[\d-.\s()]*)$
```

works fine with bellow test cases:

[image: test-string]

You can test it here : https://regex101.com/r/mS9gD7/39

Comment: phone numbers cannot start with - (dash)

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to allow `+` sign and that is only at the beginning of the number and does not want to allow any other characters or symbols other that the digits, then try the below regex:

```
var regEx = /^[+]?\d+$/;
regEx.test("+123345"); // this will be true
regEx.test("++123345"); // this will be false
regEx.test("1+23345"); // this will be false
regEx.test("111222"); // this will be true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^\+[0-9]+$
```

Try the above regex. You can test here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. Are you also looking to validate length?

Answer (score 2):

^[0-9]+[0-9]*$
try this its working

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would be nice if you provided some explanation about how and why this works though.

Comment: There must be an optional `+` at the beginning and why 2 character class when only one is needed?

Answer (score -2):

You can try this ^+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{10}$

Comment: Why [1-9]{1} then [0-9]{10} after?

Comment: I guess it's to force the first digit to be different from 0. The '{1}' bit isn't doing much though.

Comment: Don't all phone number begin with a 0 though?

Comment: Well I don't know, but I think when you have +(plus sign) you don't have 0's. I just pointed out the meaning of that regex.

Comment: + sign in the regex allow you use '+' instead of '00'

Comment: @HenryTshobo the deal was regarding '[1-9]{1}' and '[0-9]{10}' bits unless you want a number like +012345678 to be matched